# cron job not creating logs

Tags: unix, cron

I am trying to execute some sql statements using an unix script. The script is placed in crontab to run everyday at 12.00 midnight and get the output in a log file.

Though my script is running and I can see the changes in DB but the log file is not generating. However manually running the script is generating the log file. Please suggest a solution.

```
now=`date "+%d%m%y"`
LOG="table_partition_$now.log"
test=`sqlplus -s ${USER}/${CPWD}@${DB} << THEEND > $LOG
...
...
...
exit
```

This is my code snippet. Please suggest

Comment: Does the user running the cron job have the rights?

Answer (score 0):

sqlplus has no closing `

Also, can you say whether the script runs correctly outside of cron? If it only fails in cron, you may want to call

```
env > /tmp/mylatestslog.txt
```

at the start and compare the differences with your local environment. (May be differences in the user, or variables used from you personal .bashrc).

(PS. also edited the question to show one command per line.)